# Мне нужен бот на Питоне, который способен "парсить" посты Twitter и отправлять их в канал Telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, парсер, pycharm, twitter

Нужен шаблон бота на языке "**Python**", который в дальнейшем будет организован мной в **PyCharm** на
определённой библиотеке в которой будет представлен код вами. Я хочу осуществить бота, он будет
выполнять функцию "*парсинга*" постов площадки *Twitter* и отправлять их (посты с твиттера) в свой канал ***Telegram***. То есть бот в тг будет присылать в канал сообщения, которые выкладываются на
определенном аккаунте в твиттер. *Если возможно, был бы очень благодарен вашей помощи !*

Comment: Фриланс в другой стороне. Сама по себе задача звучит не сложно, так что когда появятся конкретные вопросы, вот тогда и приходите(со своим кодом).

Answer (score -1):

Я приведу пример код без использования ключей доступа:

```
import tweepy
from telegram import Bot

consumer_key = 'YOUR_TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY'
consumer_secret = 'YOUR_TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET'
access_token = 'YOUR_TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN'
access_token_secret = 'YOUR_TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET'
telegram_token = 'YOUR_TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
bot = Bot(token=telegram_token)

tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name='@TWITTER_USERNAME', count=5, tweet_mode="extended")
for tweet in tweets:
    bot.send_message(chat_id='@YOUR_CHANNEL_NAME', text=tweet.full_text)
```